# Bash terminal not allowing typing

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I am attempting to use the integrated terminal within VS Code on a Windows 10 box with the bash terminal. I have been using this same setup since March, but now it all of a sudden will not allow me to type anything in the terminal. When I start VS Code the terminal opens, but with the screen scrolled all the way down, if I scroll up I can see the command prompt. If I try to type it just scrolls back to the bottom again and doesn't type the characters. Has anyone seen this before?

Visual Studio Code 1.47.1

Git Version 2.27.0-64-bit

I have been using Git Bash while this isn't working without issue.