# Cannon type in Bash terminal after launching live-server in VS Code

Tags: bash, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I've been using Git Bash as my default terminal in VS Code since setting it up earlier this year. Now I am unable to type in the Bash terminal after launching live-server.

In order to type anything into the command line I have to open a second Bash terminal.

I changed my set up to a terminal profile in VS Code's settings.json file. I also re-installed both VS Code and Git Bash on my system with the most recent versions.

- Operating System: Windows 10
- PC
- Screenshot[image] attached of terminal and
  terminal settings from settings.json.

The only reference I can find to this issue is an unanswered stackoverflow question here - [Bash terminal not allowing typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62922389/bash-terminal-not-allowing-typing)

Can anyone help?

Comment: That's because the command is still running. Open a new terminal if you want to type, or stop the command by pressing Ctrl + C. TLDR: this is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is a path issue:

From a CMD, change the PATH (just for that CMD session, for testing) to:

```sh
set "GH=C:\Program Files\Git"
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

Then from that CMD, launch VSCode:

```
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd"
```

See if the issue persists then.